# How to add javascript in json data?

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to show image preview and caption using json and jquery. My PHP script encodes json data and sends to jquery for preview. The data contains html and javascript. In the preview I see HTML but javascript tag is omitted. I believe json parser removes this tag. Here is my code

**PHP Code**

```
$code = '
<div class="mosaic-block bar">
     <div class="mosaic-overlay">
         <div class="details">
              <h4>Sloppy Art - A Mess of Inspiration</h4>
              <p>via the Nonsense Society</p>
         </div>
     </div>
     <div class="mosaic-backdrop"><img src="http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/mosaic/florian.jpg"/></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($){$(".bar").mosaic();});</script>';

$json_msg = array('success'=>true, 'msg'=> $code);
echo encode_json($json_msg);
exit;

function encode_json ($mixed_data) {
    if(is_array($mixed_data) && isset($mixed_data['msg'])) {
        $mixed_data['msg'] = utf8_encode($mixed_data['msg']);
    }
    return json_encode($mixed_data, JSON_HEX_TAG|JSON_HEX_AMP|JSON_HEX_QUOT);
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var form_options = {
    success:        ShowPreview,
    url:            url,
    type:           'post',
    dataType:       'json',
    clearForm:      false,
    resetForm:      false,
    cache:          false,
    timeout:        200000,
};
$('.preview-form').ajaxSubmit(form_options);


function ShowPreview(data) {
    if(data.success){
        $.fn.colorbox({html:data.msg});
    }
}
```

The above code displays everything fine in colorbox except this part is missing `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($){$(".bar").mosaic();});</script>` How do I escape this javascript being parsed by json parser?

### EDIT

I can confirm the problem is with json parser. I changed datatype from json to HTML in form submit option and then I found following encoded string in response
   E\u003Cscript type=\u0022text/javascript\u0022\u003EjQuery(function($){$(\u0022.bar\u0022).mosaic();});\u003C/script\u003E

I revert back then data into json using following code 
     var data = jQuery.parseJSON(msg);

The script tag was removed from the data. Still trying to figure out why parser removes javascript tag?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2083136/returning-json-and-html-from-php-script

Comment: I made similar code on the local (but used `$.ajax()` instead of `ajaxSubmit`, first; pasted the code `$('body').append($(data.msg))`, second), and it works quite ok: in fact, when I replaced 'mosaic' call with simple alert, it gave me that nice little message. )

Comment: @raina77ow how did you submit the form using `$.ajax()`?

Comment: @jason Erm... and what prevents you from submitting the form with `$.ajax()` (supplying all the form data with `$('form').serialize()`, for example)? ajaxSubmit is just the plugin.

Comment: just learned the syntax this line is still missing `<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(function($){$(".bar").mosaic();});</script>` from HTML. When I remove < from `<script> the script code shows. Did you use `dataType:'json'`

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery(function($){...});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){...});`

That means `jQuery(function($){$(".bar").mosaic();});` Will be executed only upon `ready()` event. Since you are loading the code inside a colorbox, the `ready()` event is already fired and this snippet will never get triggered.

The best bet is to host your javascript separately and call a `$.getScript()` on the `success()` callback

If the script part itself is missing then you can create a JSON object in this way,

```
{
    html: "some html",
    js: "some js"
}
```

and then `eval()` the javascript code. (yes its bad security wise)

Also you will have to get rid of `jQuery(function($){})` part

Comment: Actually the script shown will work ok if it's placed in the `<head>` part of the document (after the jquery and all the used plugins invocation).

Comment: He is getting the script code from an ajax response. Wouldn't `ready()` event be fired already? Can you explain me please?

Comment: It will, and all the other functions wrapped in `$()` will be invoked too, yet the same code given in 'success' handler will be called as well. Check [this article](http://alexsexton.com/blog/2010/01/dont-let-document-ready-slow-you-down/) for more details.